# Javascript Object Returns TRUE but then cannot get properties, keys or values?

Tags: reactjs, json, object

React issue here

I am getting quite a strange error

```
state = { loading: true, object1: null };

async function componentDidMount() {
  const reply = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 'object1');
  const data = await reply.json();
  this.setState({ object1: data });
}

const { object1 } = this.state;
function isObject(val) {
  return val instanceof Object;
}

console.log(object1); //0
console.log(isObject(object1)); //1
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1)); //2
```

When compiling //0 and //1 everything is ok, and the output returns the array object and 'true'
When compiling //0 //1 and //2, the output returns 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Any clue on what the issue is?

Comment: Hi! I suspect you're seeing outputs from different calls to your component's `render`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (You'll have to mock the `fetch` with `setTimeout` or similar.)

Comment: At the very least, given your initial state, the first `render` will throw that error, because `object1` will be `null` because the `fetch` won't have finished yet (or even started, actually).

Comment: To my limited understanding @T-j-crowder await is handling that issue of object1 being null, and I actually can see object1 returning 'true' and showing in the console.

Comment: No, `componentDidMount` isn't called until **after** the first call to `render`, which uses your initial state, which has `object1: null`.